# Linux: Is it possible to know which options an installation was configured and compiled with?

Tags: linux, zabbix

I need to implement some web checks in our Zabbix system which requires Zabbix to be compiled with the `libcurl` (curl) option, but I don't know how to check if it was compiled with this option or not, Is there any command or file which will assist me in finding the answer?

Comment: which distribution are you using?

Comment: The distribution the server is running is CentOS 6.5 , thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`ldd(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd) to print shared library dependencies. If the `zabbix-agent` was compiled with `curl` suppport, it was linked dynamically against the `libcurl` library in compilation time.

I don't have a zabbix installation handy right now, but the procedure is simple:

```
# ldd $(which curl)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4572b000)
        libcurl.so.4 => /lib64/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f07a4189000)
        libmetalink.so.3 => /lib64/libmetalink.so.3 (0x00007f07a3f7a000)
```

You should see `libcurl` in the output. Just replace `curl` with `zabbix-agent`.

Comment: Thanks!
[root@zabbix ~]# ldd /usr/sbin/zabbix_agent
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff93fe000)
 libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007fd773094000)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to expand on dawud's answer, which was correct, but somewhat incomplete.

My environment is Debian Buster amd64 and Zabbix 4.4.5 rev b93f5c4fc0

I needed to see if pre-compiled `zabbix_server` from Zabbix repo was compiled with `libxml2` and `libcurl` for VMware monitoring, as per this article https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/vm_monitoring

So I performed:

```
# ldd /usr/sbin/zabbix_server | egrep 'libxml2|libcurl'
```

Which resulted in:

```
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f784dbd1000)
libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f784ce29000)
```

The same can obviously be done with zabbix_agent